# Dropdown semantic-ui-react scrolling overwrite pointing

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to make my dropdown list pointing to the trigger button and the to be scrolling but they do not work together. Here a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-63i9c) the code in `example.js` i added scrolling and pointing and scrolling only works and if it is removed pointing will work.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to change, but the dropdowns behave much better (the nested dropdown is properly displayed) if you remove both scrolling and pointing.

Comment: i want my dropdown to allow scrolling and pointing

Comment: Nested dropdowns and the pointing prop is currently not supported as stated in their docs: "[...] we don't currently support nested dropdowns." https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-pointing

Comment: i am not asking about the nested dropdown [another link](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-eig99) maybe this is more clear. Again i want to allow for the single dropdown ( pointing and scrolling )